# Convert SVG to Webfont with ViteJs

Tags: symfony, vite, webpack-encore, webfont-loader

Currently I'm converting the project from using Symfony Webpack Encore to ViteJs, I was using a Webpack loader called `webfonts-loader` to convert SVG to Webfont, is there any plugin for ViteJs to convert SVG to Webfont?

Answer (score 0):

Use svg files to build iconfont files(ttf,woff2,woff,eot,svg), css file, js data file and html-preview file.

https://github.com/daipeng7/rollup-plugin-iconfont